# Best Event Handler for capturing and storing the data entered in React Js Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, textbox, event-handling, mern

I have created an input textbox for entering items details. To capture and store the data entered, which among below mentioned event handler is the best?

- onClick
- onChange
- onLoad
- onKeyPress

Answer (score 0):

You need the onChange event handler to get the value of the input.
It would look like this:

`onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}`

Using `useState` hook:

`const [text, setText] = useState('')`